# how to post ng-value to mysql database

Tags: mysql, angularjs

[image]Im doing a form where I have got the ng-values displayed in my form and I have to pass that data to mysql.Im using ng-value because Im getting the datas from my page url and I have decoded it and then bounded it to the form with ng-value.
Any suggestions. Here is my sample code.

```
div class = "bodycontainer col-lg-9" ng-repeat = "x in fType">
    <form name = "logForm" class = "col-lg-12" novalidate  ng-submit = "stdCtrl.StudentCtrl()">

            <input type = "hidden"
                   id = "studentid"
                name = "studentid"
                ng-value = "x.studentid"
                ng-model = "stdCtrl.stdId"
                class = "form-control" />

        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
            <label>Firstname</label>
            <input type = "text"
                id = "first"
                name = "fname"
                ng-required = "true"
                ng-value = "x.firstname"
                ng-model = "stdCtrl.fName"
                class = "form-control"
                autofocus
                placeholder = "FirstName" ></input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Lastname</label>
            <input type = "text"
                   name = "lname"
                   ng-required = "true"
                   ng-value = "x.lastname"
                   ng-model = "stdCtrl.lName"
                   class = "form-control"
                   placeholder = "LastName"></input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-12">
        <label>Gender:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" ngValue = "x.gender" ng-model="stdCtrl.gender"  required>Male</input>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" ngValue = "x.gender" ng-model="stdCtrl.gender"  required>Female</input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Email</label>
            <input type = "email"
                   name = "email"
                   ng-required = "true"
                   ng-value = "x.email"
                   ng-model = "stdCtrl.Email"
                   class = "form-control"
                   placeholder = "Your Email" ></input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Fathername</label>
            <input type = "text"
                   name = "fathername"
                   ng-required = "true"
                   ng-value = "x.fathername"
                   ng-model = "stdCtrl.Fname"
                   class = "form-control"
                   placeholder = "Father's Name"></input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Mothername</label>
            <input type = "text"
                   name = "mothername"
                   ng-required = "true"
                   ng-value = "x.mothername"
                   ng-model = "stdCtrl.Mname"
                   class = "form-control"
                   placeholder = "Mother's Name"></input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>DOB</label>
            <input type = "text"
                   id = "birthdayPicker"
                   name = "birthdy"
                   ng-required = "true"
                   ng-value = "x.birthday"
                   ng-model = "stdCtrl.brthdy"
                   class = "form-control"
                   placeholder = "DOB-Date Of Birth"></input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-12">
        <label>Home-Address</label>
            <textarea name = "address"
                ng-required = "true"
                ng-bind = "x.address"
                ng-model = "stdCtrl.address"
                class = "form-control"
                placeholder = "PresentAddress"
                row = "10" cols = "50" ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>10<sup>th</sup>-Percentage</label>
            <input type = "number"
                   name = "ten"
                   ng-required = "true"
                   ng-model = "stdCtrl.tenth"
                   ng-value = "x.tenth"
                   class = "form-control"
                   placeholder = "10th percentage"></input>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>12<sup>th</sup>-Percentage</label>
            <input type = "number"
                   name = "twelve"
                   ng-required = "true"
                   ng-value = "x.twelfth"
                   ng-model = "stdCtrl.twelfth"
                   class = "form-control"
                   placeholder = "12th percentage"></input>
        </div>
```

Here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyForm',[])
app.controller('StudentControl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$scope.StudentCtrl = function(){
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
   };
 var fType = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($scope.StudentCtrl()['data']));
console.log(fType);
$scope.fType = fType;
}]);
```

So my aim is to how can I send back the ng-value data to mysql database so that I can save it and can bring back to my view table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post the data to your backend app, this one will manage the mysql operations.

You don't need the `ng-value`, you have to use the `ng-model` values, so you can do something like this:

```
app.controller('StudentControl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.userData = {};

        $scope.submitForm = function () {
          var req = {
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://example.com/your/backend/api',
              data: $scope.userData
          }

          $http(req).then(function(resp) {
              // Post OK do something
          }, function(err) {
              // Post KO do something
          });
        }
    }
]);
```

I can also suggest to change the `ng-model` to `userData.<fieldname>` and use `$scope.userData`

```
 <input type = "text"
            id = "first"
            name = "fname"
            ng-required = "true"
            ng-model = "userData.fName"
            class = "form-control"
            autofocus
            placeholder = "FirstName" ></input>
```

You probably need also to create an external div to include everything an place there `ng-controller="StudentControl"` then change the `ng-submit` too:

```
<div ng-controller="StudentControl">
   <div class = "bodycontainer col-lg-9" ng-repeat = "x in fType">
      <form name = "logForm" class = "col-lg-12" novalidate  ng-submit = "submitForm()">
      [...]
```

Comment: how can check my form values because when I tried console.log it says undefined

Comment: when I checked the console of $scope.stdCtrl I got object array but when I opened it, it was empty

Comment: still im getting empty object in my console.

Comment: check the image I uploaded in the question where $scope.userData is empty object

Comment: so I have to push my ng-controller from my <body> tag to another new <div> and also I have to change the ng-submit name?

Comment: Still empty and do you notice that I have decoded the values using json.parse and then returned the values of their own fields.

Comment: please check with my json.parse which I have binded using ng-value and is there anyway to make the new values to go under ng-model

Comment: Michelem, I found one error. The ng-repeat datas which I decoded and sent back to the form aren't active but when I make changes to particular text field then Im getting that particular data in console.log. Please check the updated image in my question